# How can I select only all edited photos from a catalog for export from Lightroom 3?

Tags: software, lightroom, lightroom-3, file-management, camera-controls

In Lightroom 3, how do I select *only* edited photos from a catalog for export, without choosing individually?

For example: I import 500 photos from a shoot and I go through and edit 286 photos. Now I want to export only the 286 edited photos, and I don't want to slowly go through all 500 images selecting individually with my mouse and command key.

I know that I can use flags and select only flagged photos but that method isn't sufficient. How do I quickly select only the edited photos?

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to do this is using a **smart collection**. You can use the **Has Adjustments** filter to show just edited photos, or the **Edit Date** filter to choose photos edited within a specific time period.

I have a smart collection called "Edited this week" which is great for easily getting back to the photos I've recently worked on.

Comment: Smart collections are a very powerful and often underused feature of Lightroom. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

Below presets/snapshots/history/folders in the left lane, click on the plus beside *collections(Ctrl+shift+3)* -> *create smart collection..* -> give a name-> check *inside a collection set* -> smart corrections -> match all -> develop -> has adjustments -> create.

When ever you need to see only the modified files, you can select this smart collection by clicking on the triangle near the current file name in the *film strip(f6)* panel.